# Problems installing OpenMPI locally for use with CUDA

Tags: c++, makefile, ubuntu-16.04, openmpi

## Short Version

I have CUDA code I need to run locally. Thus, I am trying to install OpenMPI following [the OpenMPI directions](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#easy-build). When I try to `make` my code, I receive [very long error output](https://www.mediafire.com/?9j9q3gitync2a9p), similar to what is described by the [OpenMPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#build-intel-compilers). I tried to reinstall OpenMPI with the documentation's suggested fix, but now I get these errors during installation:

```
Making all in tools/ompi_info
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi/tools/ompi_info'
  CC       ompi_info.o
  CC       param.o
  CCLD     ompi_info
ld: warning: libimf.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libsvml.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libirng.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libintlc.so.5, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: .libs/ompi_info: hidden symbol `__intel_cpu_features_init_x' in /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libirc.a(cpu_feature_disp.o) is referenced by DSO
ld: final link failed: Bad value
Makefile:1785: recipe for target 'ompi_info' failed
make[2]: *** [ompi_info] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi/tools/ompi_info'
Makefile:3353: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi'
Makefile:1806: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! S.O.S.!

## Long Version

I have CUDA code I need to run locally. Thus, I am trying to install OpenMPI following [the OpenMPI directions](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#easy-build). I have the tar stored as `~/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz`. Hance, I ran

```
$gunzip -c openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz | tar xf -
$cd openmpi-2.1.1
$./configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi-2.1.1 &> configure_log1
$sudo make all install &> install_log_take1
```

with success. Note that I changed the `--prefix=/usr/local` in the directions to `--prefix=/opt/openmpi-2.1.1`. I have included [configure_log1](https://www.mediafire.com/?67h69bwlb2d5w6d) and [install_log_take1](https://www.mediafire.com/?vz9w89ln4nw6489).

When I try to `make` my code using my makefile [makefile.ulfhednar](https://www.mediafire.com/?rhqiu1dqxip0lfh),

```
$make -f makefile.ulfhednar clean
$make -f makefile.ulfhednar &> make_log1
```

I receive a very long error output in [make_log1](https://www.mediafire.com/?9j9q3gitync2a9p) that looks similar to what is described by the [OpenMPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#build-intel-compilers). It says the solution is to install OpenMPI with the configure options "`./configure CC=icc CXX=icpc F77=ifort FC=ifort ...`", so I reinstalled using the commands,

```
$cd ~/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1
$sudo make uninstall
$sudo rm -r /opt/openmpi-2.1.1
$cd ..
$sudo rm -r openmpi-2.1.1

$gunzip -c openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz | tar xf -
$cd openmpi-2.1.1

$which icc
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/icc
$which icpc
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/icpc
$which ifort
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/ifort

$./configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi-2.1.1 CC=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/icc CXX=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/icpc F77=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/ifort FC=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/ifort &> configure_log2
$sudo make all install &> install_log_take2
```

Here is [configure_log2](https://www.mediafire.com/?j9l7d94szwpa1gc) and [install_log_take2](https://www.mediafire.com/?ff7i7f6hl4ubfr9). Of note in `install_log_take2` are the following lines:

```
Making all in tools/ompi_info
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi/tools/ompi_info'
  CC       ompi_info.o
  CC       param.o
  CCLD     ompi_info
ld: warning: libimf.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libsvml.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libirng.so, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libintlc.so.5, needed by ../../../ompi/.libs/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: .libs/ompi_info: hidden symbol `__intel_cpu_features_init_x' in /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libirc.a(cpu_feature_disp.o) is referenced by DSO
ld: final link failed: Bad value
Makefile:1785: recipe for target 'ompi_info' failed
make[2]: *** [ompi_info] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi/tools/ompi_info'
Makefile:3353: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hatfull/Downloads/openmpi-2.1.1/ompi'
Makefile:1806: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Sorry I had to upload all the log files to mediafire, pastebin didn't accept them because they were too large.

What am I doing wrong? Please help! S.O.S.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution!!!

I logged into `root` and ran through the installation steps without using sudo.

```
#gunzip -c openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz | tar xf -
#cd openmpi-2.1.1
#./configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi-2.1.1 CC=icc CXX=icpc FC=ifort
#make all install
```

I was trying to use OpenMPI with the Intel Composer compilers and this was causing permissions issues. I followed the installation instructions found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-building-open-mpi-with-the-intel-compilers), but I got the same problems I had before when trying to install. The issue was that the linker, `ld` "could not find" the proper libraries because those libraries are no longer provided in the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable when `sudo` is called. The only way to circumvent this is by logging into the `root` user and setting your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to be identical to the one your normal user has.

I had been stuck on this for *days* and I'm jumping for joy now that it's sorted out! I hope this helps someone else in the future.